# Бесплатный доступ к Google API на год, какие ограничения?

Tags: google-translate

Я добавил в google developers свою кредитную карту, и мне автоматически был открыт бесплатный доступ на целый год к их API, я так понимаю в тестовом режиме. После прошествия года, этот доступ будет стоить что-то около 300 с лишним долларов. Из всех сервисов с доступом через API, мне нужен только доступ к автопереводу Google Translate. Автоматический перевод работает(через скрипт) но переводится не более 1000 символов.

Исходя из всего вышенаписанного два вопроса:

1. Как сделать доступ только к Google Translate, доступ к остальным сервисам за 300$ в год абсолютно не нужен, на сколько я знаю API Google Translate стоит около 20$?
2. Как в этом тестовом годичном периоде увеличить возможность автоматического перевода текста хотя бы до 5000 на статью?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как его адресовать в  соответствующую техподдержку?

Comment: можно начинать отсюда: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/translate